# How to pass blob to the viewer.js in PDF.js and how to display pdf in separate window

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, frontend, pdf.js

I have loaded the pdf in canvas but unable to pass it to viewer.js in PDF.js.
Examples only show how to pass to canvas not to viewer.js and i want to load the pdf in different window

Comment: Need more details

Comment: i am able to create canvas .. which is mentioned in https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/index.html#interactive-examples ......... but i am unable to create pdf in new window and i want to integrate in angular 4

Answer (score 1):

It took me an entire day to get pdf.js viewer.html working.

This is how I am able to render decoded base64 data using pdf.js viewer.html

(Add pdf.js includes)

1. Add an iFrame to your html page.

Here's mine. I use PHP.

```
<iframe id="pdfViewer" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/includes/pdfjs/web/viewer.html'?>" style="width: 100%; height: 515px;" allowfullscreen="" webkitallowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

2. Next, get your iframe in Javascript and set the decoded data as shown

   ```
    // data is already decoded from base64 in previous steps
    var pdfjsframe = document.getElementById('pdfViewer');
    pdfjsframe.contentWindow.PDFViewerApplication.open(data);
   ```

that's it!

Comment: What previous steps?

Answer (score -1):

PDF.js comes with a viewer.  You can embed an iframe/frame in your page, or open a new window.  The url will be the same for both:

`pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=URL_TO_YOU_PDF`

You can also pass binary data:

```
// atob() is used to convert base64 encoded PDF to binary-like data.
// (See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/
// Base64_encoding_and_decoding.)
var pdfData = atob(
  'JVBERi0xLjcKCjEgMCBvYmogICUgZW50cnkgcG9pbnQKPDwKICAvVHlwZSAvQ2F0YWxvZwog' +
  'IC9QYWdlcyAyIDAgUgo+PgplbmRvYmoKCjIgMCBvYmoKPDwKICAvVHlwZSAvUGFnZXMKICAv' +
  'TWVkaWFCb3ggWyAwIDAgMjAwIDIwMCBdCiAgL0NvdW50IDEKICAvS2lkcyBbIDMgMCBSIF0K' +
  'Pj4KZW5kb2JqCgozIDAgb2JqCjw8CiAgL1R5cGUgL1BhZ2UKICAvUGFyZW50IDIgMCBSCiAg' +
  'L1Jlc291cmNlcyA8PAogICAgL0ZvbnQgPDwKICAgICAgL0YxIDQgMCBSIAogICAgPj4KICA+' +
  'PgogIC9Db250ZW50cyA1IDAgUgo+PgplbmRvYmoKCjQgMCBvYmoKPDwKICAvVHlwZSAvRm9u' +
  'dAogIC9TdWJ0eXBlIC9UeXBlMQogIC9CYXNlRm9udCAvVGltZXMtUm9tYW4KPj4KZW5kb2Jq' +
  'Cgo1IDAgb2JqICAlIHBhZ2UgY29udGVudAo8PAogIC9MZW5ndGggNDQKPj4Kc3RyZWFtCkJU' +
  'CjcwIDUwIFRECi9GMSAxMiBUZgooSGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkISkgVGoKRVQKZW5kc3RyZWFtCmVu' +
  'ZG9iagoKeHJlZgowIDYKMDAwMDAwMDAwMCA2NTUzNSBmIAowMDAwMDAwMDEwIDAwMDAwIG4g' +
  'CjAwMDAwMDAwNzkgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwMDE3MyAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDAwMzAxIDAw' +
  'MDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDAzODAgMDAwMDAgbiAKdHJhaWxlcgo8PAogIC9TaXplIDYKICAvUm9v' +
  'dCAxIDAgUgo+PgpzdGFydHhyZWYKNDkyCiUlRU9G');

// Loaded via <script> tag, create shortcut to access PDF.js exports.
var pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];

// The workerSrc property shall be specified.
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = '//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js';

// Using DocumentInitParameters object to load binary data.
var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument({data: pdfData});
loadingTask.promise.then(function(pdf) {
  console.log('PDF loaded');

  // Fetch the first page
  var pageNumber = 1;
  pdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(function(page) {
    console.log('Page loaded');

    var scale = 1.5;
    var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

    // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
    var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.height = viewport.height;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;

    // Render PDF page into canvas context
    var renderContext = {
      canvasContext: context,
      viewport: viewport
    };
    var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
    renderTask.then(function () {
      console.log('Page rendered');
    });
  });
}, function (reason) {
  // PDF loading error
  console.error(reason);
});
```

See https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/index.html#interactive-examples for more information.

Comment: thanks for response ... I am trying to integrate in angular 4 .... and the example which you mentioned creates PDF in canvas in same page .. which is a image ... I want a sample example which takes blob as input and produces output in new window which is a PDF

Comment: I am searching for solution which works both in chrome and IE 11 .... and @john-manko the example which u posted will not have intraction with viewer .... i want a example which takes blob as input and produces *PDF* as output and how to pass the blob to viewer.html????

Comment: Have you tried using a URL such as `pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=file://BASE64_DATA`

Comment: can you provide complete project or demo ... So that i can understand and implement it ..............and did u implement pdf.js in Angular2 or 4 or 5 or 6 if yes please provide git or demo ...

Comment: @JohnManko it's no use coping the code from the official documentation. of course that's where we lean't about the library but we are here on stackoverflow to find other ways to use the library (like eat from a plate sideways or upsidedown, 45 degree angle etc, no one uses the same thing the same way)