# Load PDF base64 encoded into the viewer.js of PDF.JS

Tags: javascript, base64, pdf.js

I'm fighting with PDF.JS. All I want is to ignore to add a pdf file in the GET-Paramter, for real.. who does this today??

So my problem is, I'm trying to load a pdf file into my loaded pdf.js-file. I want to use viewer.html and the viewer.js. The file is served as base64-encoded-string. For tests I am loading the base64 code into the html to have directly access over Javascript.

What files I'm loading:

- build/pdf.js
- build/pdf.worker.js
- web/viewer.js

No loading errors

```
    var BASE64_MARKER = ';base64,';
    var pdfAsArray = convertDataURIToBinary("data:application/pdf;base64, " + document.getElementById('pdfData').value);


    pdfjsLib.getDocument(pdfAsArray).then(function (pdf) {
        //var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        console.log(pdfjsLib);
        pdf.getPage(1).then(function(page) {
            // you can now use *page* here
            var scale = 1.5;
            var viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: scale, });
            // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions.
            var canvas = document.getElementById('viewer');
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.height = viewport.height;
            canvas.width = viewport.width;
            // Render PDF page into canvas context.
            var renderContext = {
              canvasContext: context,
              viewport: viewport,
            };
            page.render(renderContext);
        });

      //pdfjsLib.load(pdf);
    })


    function convertDataURIToBinary(dataURI) {
            var base64Index = dataURI.indexOf(BASE64_MARKER) + BASE64_MARKER.length;
            var base64 = dataURI.substring(base64Index);
            var raw = window.atob(base64);
            var rawLength = raw.length;
            var array = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(rawLength));

            for (i = 0; i < rawLength; i++) {
                array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
            }
            return array;
       }
```

Console.log here is..
      {build: "d7afb74a", version: "2.2.228", getDocument: ƒ, LoopbackPort: ƒ, PDFDataRangeTransport: ƒ, …}

The PDF comes right and I can see Javascript gives me a correct console.log. I can see it has 2 pages and more than 1MB data. So I think the code and pdf is okay.

So and now I dont't want to use a fkn canvas. (I only saw tutorials where users working with canvas and not with the viewer.html) I'm not going to work with iframes,canvas or objects. I just want that the viewer.js is taking MY pdf not any other. (example.pdf)

I want that pdf.js is loading the pdf im parsing with PHP and onload it should just appears. PHP is giving the pdf base64 encoded.

I saw the article on the docu of pdf.js: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#file

> You can use raw binary data to open a PDF document: use Uint8Array instead of URL in the PDFViewerApplication.open call. If you have base64 encoded data, please decode it first -- not all browsers have atob or data URI scheme support. (The base64 conversion operation uses more memory, so we recommend delivering raw PDF data as typed array in first place.)

What a nice tipp. BUT nobody says where you have access to PDFViewerApplication. If I do this:

```
pdfjsLib.PDFViewerApplication.open(pdfAsArray);
```

I will get an error like 'open is not a function' (i tried with load() too)

Sry for my bad english, hope you understand my problem and can help me ..

Comment: where is your `viewer.html` loaded? here is an answer where the PDF gets loaded inside an iframe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52412417/5334486

Comment: As I mentioned, I dont want to load the PDF in an Iframe. It makes no sense to me. I also want to show the pdf on mobile views. That could be a problem with an iframe.

Also the HTML is no problem, I load the HTML with Codeigniter and I get the viewer perfectly rendered in my view.

Comment: I don't understand WHERE you want to render your PDF

Comment: @GrafiCode - if you download pdf.js, viewer.html and viewer.js is included. I took these files and put them into my file where I want to display the file. So I have a site like.. base_url/viewPdf/1 (ID of PDF). So PHP knows -> readfile(pdf-1.pdf) and store base64 encoded string into a variable (for now -> future it should load via ajax). 

Next step: PHP loads a view (pdf.php) with headers, body and so on. There I include the viewer.html. The Browser is displaying the site correctly. Viewer.js and other externals are loaded perfectly. NOW I want to display the PDF I get from php.

Comment: if you include `viewer.html` than can you pass query parameters to it, like `viewer.html?file={pdfAsArray}` ?

Comment: Sry for the late answer. I changed the application to Viewer.Js. Over viewer.js I am able to pass a simple url which responses a base64 encoded PDF. Thats working for me. I know Viewer.js is just an extension to pdf.js and uses this library. But I don't know why it's not working with the viewer.html from pdf.js

Comment: Pretty sure you can use the session storage object: 
 https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/11369; But not 100% sure.